# NextAuth: How can I attach my JWT token to every axios call?

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am building a Next.js application.

For authentication, I am using NextAuth.

For making HTTP calls, I am using Axios.

The problem I am facing is that I want to attach the JWT with every axios call I make.

I have an axios instance created as:

`axios-client.js`

```
const ApiClient = () => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL,
  };

  const instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(`error`, error);
      throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
    },
  );

  return instance;
};

export default ApiClient();
```

I can get the jwt from getSession() function provided by next-auth.

But the problem is that function is asynchronous. If I try to get jwt from this from the getSession() function, I always get a "Promise" instead of value.

PS: I am using Strapi which sends the JWT after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you `await` the response from `getSession()` and add it as a header to your request. Note that you don't have to reinitialize axios client each time, you can reuse it.

Comment: It's needed to pass context or req to getSession